# Why is my loop executed too often?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am designing a program for a C++ class that I am taking and the professor wants us to make a program that outputs a diamond shape using "*". The thing I am stuck on is that my program is outputting too many lines.

Instead of

```
 *
***
 *
```

It is outputting

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

How would I modify my code to get this to work? I have been searching online for an answer all morning with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    //Define Varaible
    int N;

   cout << "Please enter a postitive integer: ";
   cin  >> N;
   cout << "Here is your diamond." << endl << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= 2 * N; j++) {
         if (i <= N) {
            if (j < N - i || j > N + i) {
               cout << ' ';
            }
            else {
               cout << '*';
            }
         }
         else {
            if (j < i - N || j > 3 * N - i) {
               cout << ' ';
            }
            else {
               cout << '*';
            }
         }
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With what input do you get those "wrong" images? If you get 1 line too many and don't understand your own code (...?), add "N = N - 1;" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get more rows than you expect is that you are creating `2 * N + 1` number of rows, when you actually want `2 * N - 1`.

The fix is simple: Decrement `N` by one after you read the input.

```
   cin  >> N;
   assert(N > 0);
   --N;
```

This way, the rest of your code won't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that in range [0,5] (both inclusive) there are 6 elements, not 5. So when you do loops and you want to do 5 iterations you usually do either:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) // do stuff
```

or

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i ) // do stuff
```

When programming in C or C++ first version is used more often as it fits array indexes and programmers have habit to use that form.
But as I said before if you do:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i ) // do stuff
```

That would be 6 iterations.